# Android loop through GridView child elements

Tags: android, gridview, sudoku

I'm creating a Sudoku app but having a problem -- I'm trying to hide only certain elements on the grid, and I can do so using getView(), but anytime I use the EditText to change a value and move the keyboard down, getView() is called again and it wipes the input, so I'm trying to find a way around it. I believe the way to do this is to simply loop through the elements and hide certain elements in onCreate(), although I'm having problems getting any children of the view. I can use getChildAt(i), although this only returns the data, not the view itself, so I cannot change the visibility. I've also tried using getChildAt() solution from a previous Stackoverflow answer, but it seems to not work.

Heres my code:

MainActivity:

```
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static java.lang.Boolean.FALSE;
import static java.lang.Boolean.TRUE;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public GridView gridView;
    public String[] items = new String[]{
            "5","3","4","6","7","8","9","1","2",
            "6","7","2","1","9","5","3","4","8",
            "1","9","8","3","4","2","5", "6","7",
            "8","5","9","7","6","1","4","2","3",
            "4","2","6","8","5","3","7","9","1",
            "7","1","3","9","2", "4","8","5","6",
            "9","6","1","5","3","7","2","8","4",
            "2","8","7","4","1","9","6","3","5",
            "3","4","5", "2","8","6","1","7","9"
    };

    public Boolean[] masker = new Boolean[]{
            TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
            TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE,
            FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE,
            TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE,
            TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE,
            TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE,
            FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE,
            FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE,
            FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE,
    };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        gridView = (GridView) this.findViewById(R.id.myGridView);
        CustomGridAdapter gridAdapter = new CustomGridAdapter(MainActivity.this, items, masker);
        gridView.setAdapter(gridAdapter);

        final int size = gridAdapter.getCount();
        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            ViewGroup gridChild = (ViewGroup) gridView.getChildAt(i);
            int childSize = gridChild.getChildCount();
            for(int k = 0; k < childSize; k++) {
                gridChild.getChildAt(k);
            }
        }

    }


}
```

CustomGridAdapter:

```
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.text.Editable;
    import android.text.TextWatcher;
    import android.view.KeyEvent;
    import android.view.LayoutInflater;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.ViewGroup;
    import android.view.inputmethod.EditorInfo;
    import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
    import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;

    import static java.lang.Boolean.FALSE;

    public class CustomGridAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


            private Context context;
            private String[] items;
            private Boolean[] masker;
            private String input;
            private EditText t;
            LayoutInflater inflater;

            public CustomGridAdapter(Context context, String[] items, Boolean[] masker ){
                this.context = context;
                this.items = items;
                this.masker = masker;

                inflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            }

            public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
                if(convertView == null){
                    convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cell, null);
                }

                t = (EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.editCell);

                if(masker[position]){
                    t.setText(items[position]);
                    t.setEnabled(FALSE);
                }else{
                    t.setText("");
                }

                if( (position % 9 != 0) && (position % 3 == 0) ){
                    t.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.columnborder);
                }
                if( (position >= 18 && position <= 26) || (position >= 45 && position <= 53) ){
                    t.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.rowborder);
                }
                if( (position == 21 || position == 24 || position == 48 || position == 51 ) ){
                    t.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.cornerborder);
                }

                return convertView;
            }

            @Override
            public int getCount() { return items.length; }

            @Override
            public Object getItem(int position) { return items[position]; }

            @Override
            public long getItemId(int position) { return position; }


    }
```

Essentially, I want only want to hide certain elements of the grid for Sudoku, but I don't think I can do it in getView() because it will keep resetting values because of t.setText("");.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is completely wrong.  You should never alter the views in a GridView except in during getView.  You manipulate a GridView via its adapter and the data it holds.  For example, lets say you had a Adapter backed by a list of strings, and you wanted to hide every other string.  YOu'd have two choices then-  change the list to hold only every other string, or change the data it holds to hold both a string and a visibility, and honor both in getView.

The entire point of a GridView (or ListView, or RecyclerView) is that its a data backed view that will recycle to match the data.  If you start trying to manipulate views yourself, that breaks badly.  Don't do that-  manipulate the data, then tell the view to update itself.

Comment: Very useful comment, thanks! I could've just simply removed the setText(""); and made each cell empty from the start which fixed the issue.